# Появление блока (часть 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как действовать на блок в центре экрана я разобрался ! Но если к примеру блоков 3 и больше то как это можно сделать ?
Писать 100 ID не хорошо ! 
Хотя всё работает но не могу же я точно знать сколько статей будет

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu a').each(function() {
    var location = window.location.href;
    var link = this.href;
    if (location == link) {
      $(this).addClass('linkof');
    }
  });
});


var $win = $(window);
var $marker = $('.post');
var $marker1 = $('#post1');
var $marker2 = $('#post2');

$win.scroll(function() {

  if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() / 2 >= $marker.offset().top) {
    $("#post").addClass("center");
  } else {
    $("#post").removeClass('center');
  }
});

$win.scroll(function() {

  if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() / 2 >= $marker1.offset().top) {
    $("#post1").addClass("center");
  } else {
    $("#post1").removeClass('center');
  }
});

$win.scroll(function() {

  if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() / 2 >= $marker2.offset().top) {
    $("#post2").addClass("center");
  } else {
    $("#post2").removeClass('center');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#body1 .link>a {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.linkof {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 4px 14px;
  animation: color 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.post {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#body3 .post:first-of-type {
  opacity: 1!important;
}

.post h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.post img,
p {
  float: left;
}

.post p {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.center {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s
}
```

```html
<body id="body3">
  <h2>Страница со статьями</h2>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Статьи</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">О нас</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="post" class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="post1" class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/no_thumb.jpg" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>

  <div id="post2" class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/thumb-jpg.png" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").css("opacity", "1");
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, лучше использовать циклы и ссылки на объекты.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu a').each(function() {
    var location = window.location.href;
    var link = this.href;
    if (location == link) {
      $(this).addClass('linkof');
    }
  });
});


var $win = $(window);
var markersOffsets = $('.post').map(function(i, el) {
  var $el = $(el);
  return {el: $el,top: $el.offset().top};
});

$win.scroll(function() {
    markersOffsets.each(function(i, markerOffset) {
        var $el = markerOffset.el,
          top = markerOffset.top;
        if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() / 2 >= top) {
          $el.addClass("center");
        } else {
          $el.removeClass('center');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s;
}

.clear,
.clear:after,
.clear:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#body1 .link>a {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

a {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.linkof {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 4px 14px;
  animation: color 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.post {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#body3 .post:first-of-type {
  opacity: 1!important;
}

.post h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.post img,
p {
  float: left;
}

.post p {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.center {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="body3">
  <h2>Страница со статьями</h2>

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="page.html">Статьи</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">О нас</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/default.jpg" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/no_thumb.jpg" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="post clear">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <img src="img/thumb-jpg.png" alt="" width="150px">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ut officiis, accusamus porro eaque sint, assumenda in magnam amet vitae animi aspernatur minus, iste voluptates beatae laboriosam aut quas modi!</p>
  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").css("opacity", "1");
    });
  </script>
```